# Lets and allow change sentences, why?

Tags: verbs, predicate-frames

I have just come across something that I have never thought about before and it occurred to me that this site would be the place to ask.

The dictionary defines ALLOW as: VERB - let (someone) have or do something.

The dictionary defines LET as: VERB - not prevent or forbid; allow.

So the dictionary uses each word to define the other word. This suggests to me they are likely synonyms.

However if I have this sentence, "doing this allows you to jump higher" I cannot simply just change the word ALLOWS to LETS because the word TO makes the sentence sound wrong; "doing this lets you to jump higher".

Similarly, if I have the sentence "doing this lets you jump higher" and I change the word LETS to ALLOWS, it again sounds wrong; "doing this allows you jump higher".

So my question is, is there a simple reason why, while both words look to be interchangeable at a definition level, choosing either of the words also changes which other words you need in the sentence to make it complete or sound correctly structured?

Comment: That's because each verb has a set of certain patterns by which it connects its dependents, that's called [**government** or **rection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_(linguistics)). Two verbs can be synonyms but still have different rection, that's the case with _allow_ and _let_.

Comment: That is good enough for me :D

Comment: *So the dictionary uses each word to define the other word. This suggests to me they are likely synonyms.* This is an error. There is a common misconception that English has a lot of synonyms. It does not. It has **very, very few** synonyms. The guidance is that some words have an overlap in meaning **in some restricted contexts** but all differing words retain their nuances. "Let" implies (i) "to raise no objection to something" - "He let me drive the car." (ii) the subjunctive imperative - "Let there be light!" ; "Allow" implies "the granting of permission" "He allowed me to drive the car."

Comment: (1) 'Synonym' means 'one of in the first instance a pair of words that may in some instances be interchanged with no or negligible change in meaning'.  // (2) The dictionary definitions are misleading; they attempt to explain similarity of meaning but do not clearly address the different distributions of the words. This is why example sentences are needful. @Yellow sky is more precise here.  'The new laws _allowed them to_ meet in groups of up to 8' =  'The new laws _let them_ meet in groups of up to 8'.  / And note that 'more choices allow more faults' is not easily paraphrasable using 'let'.

Comment: @Greybeard You're choosing the strictest definition for 'synonym'. The term becomes nigh on meaningless. The more commonly used definition, given above, is the one used in dictionaries such as M-W, Lexico, Macmillan, and Collins, who provide 'lists of synonyms'.

Comment: Maybe  it would help to see that *let* is very close to *allow to*, not allow alone: Let me say, Allow me to say.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am aware of what you write and appreciate what you are trying to do, but non-native speakers take things very literally (See the OP) and think they are always interchangeable. The essence of correcting the error is to say *"The guidance is that some words have an overlap in meaning in some restricted contexts but all differing words retain their nuances."* I append in the comment below the OED definition of "synonym".

Comment: OED *Synonym: 1. Strictly, a word having the same sense as another (in the same language); but more usually, either or any of two or more words (in the same language) having the same general sense, but possessing each of them meanings which are not shared by the other or others, or having different shades of meaning or implications appropriate to different contexts: e.g. serpent, snake; ship, vessel; glad, happy, joyful, joyous; to kill, slay, slaughter; to grieve, mourn, lament, sorrow.* Now you can say that every time, or say there are no synonyms or some "**close/near** synonyms.

Comment: @Greybeard The focus of ELU is providing a searchable database at linguist standard. It is not intended to be a Q and A site for learners (that is why ELL was set up) and answers need to be as precise as possible. Others (and OP) will doubtless encounter the problem that 'synonym' has a default meaning other than 'words always interchangeable'. And a meaning almost all linguists choose. It is 'strict synonym' that needs the qualifier.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In all fairness, if  a question has been asked and has not been marked as closed, it is open for comments, or flagging. Comments are aimed at addressing the question at what is perceived to be the level of the poster. You will note who has made comments.

Comment: @Greybeard I don't think that 'synonym' = 'one of two (or more) words identical in meaning and totally interchangeable in all contexts' is going to help _anybody_. The word is hardly ever used this way. A learner might take this as being  (or feel  confirmed in their suspicion that it is) 'the definition'. Such a definition without a caveat is highly misleading; the learner will start mixing and matching all words given in the many 'lists of synonyms' provided by reputable reference works.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am no longer sure what you mean by "*Such a definition without a caveat*" when I clearly wrote *The guidance is that some words have an overlap in meaning in some restricted contexts but all differing words retain their nuances.*

Comment: @Greybeard 'There is a common misconception that English has a lot of synonyms. It does not. It has very, very few synonyms.' is given far too much prominence and is an arrogation.

Comment: Thanks everyone that commented on this, this thread has been great to read, you are all very knowledgeable. I would like to point out this line "This suggests to me they are likely synonyms." I note the word suggests, not confirms. I'm a native speaker, the only reason this question came about was due to someone writing LET but structuring the sentence for ALLOWS. It made me think "why are the words not directly interchangeable even though the dictionary makes it look like they are synonyms?" Having never thought about it before I posted the question, I'm now more informed. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because two words have similar meanings does not mean they are interchangeable—almost no two words are truly interchangeable, on several levels. Particularly here, two words being similar in meaning does not mean their grammar needs to be similar, either. Every verb has its own conventions as to which complements are accepted or not.

When using a verb form to indicate an activity which is being made possible, *allow* takes a to-infinitive as an object complement or a gerund as a direct object, e.g.

> This allows you to jump
>
> This allows jumping

This is also the case with *authorize*, *license*, *enable*, *approve*, *release*, *sanction*, *okay*, *suffer*, *bless*, *warrant*, and *green-light* among some other verbs of permission, approval, or empowerment.

*Let* only accepts a bare infinitive as an object complement for the same, and is the only common verb of permission, approval, etc. I can think of which does.

Comment: "Let only accepts a bare infinitive as an object complement for the same, and is the only common verb I can think of which does." "This lets you jump" "I saw you jump" "I heard you speak" -- the same syntax, no?

Comment: @RosieF How are *see* and *hear* verbs of permission?

Comment: Ah... in that case I've misunderstood you. I was going by your words "Let ... is the only common verb I can think of which does" which doesn't contain the word "permission". I now see that your previous para mentions "verbs of permission, approval, or empowerment."

Comment: Ah, you're right, I should be more clear. I hope the edit is an improvement.